# Do any Food businesses have stock times over one hour?

Tags: ios, tiny-tower

I've noticed that in Tiny Tower most of the Food category businesses have very short restock times and thus very low stock count. Any time I don't check the game for more than 15 minutes my restaurants are always out of stock, and I'm usually out of stock before I can stock a second item.

I found the Donut Shop actually has very deep stock with long restock times; two hours to restock almost 3000 bearclaws. Do any other restaurants have stocks this large?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Tiny Tower Wiki's page](http://tinytowerwiki.com/Food) on Food Floors, there are a few businesses that take over an hour to stock (at level one; the times increase as you level up the businesses):

- **Bakery**: Bread Loaf (3 hours)
- **BBQ Place**: BBQ Sandwich (1 hour), Beef Ribs (3 hours, 40 minutes)
- **Donut Shop**: Bearclaws (3 hours, 25 minutes)
- **Pancake House**: Berry Pancakes (2 hours), Big Stack (6 hours, 40 minutes)
- **Scoops**: Ice Cream Cake (3 hours)

Comment: Doh, I should have known to search for a wiki! Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad my answer helped.

Comment: I just wanted to add "thanks" for taking the time to transcribe the data into this wiki.  Th last several times I've looked at the TT wiki, I've gotten malware warnings from my browser. Which is a perfect example of why answers should include data, not just links!

Comment: Some of the newer floors have a higher stock time: Cheese Shop, Italian, and Seafood come to mind. Do you mind if I edit your question directly when I can get the specifics?